# phpMyAdmin displaying varbinary columns in Hex allthough "show in Hex" is unchecked

Tags: phpmyadmin

phpMayAdmin 4 (frameless Version)

I'm wondering whether someone else has encountered this problem:

on all columns of type "varbinary", phpMyAdmin converts shown values from a query to Hex. On the options tab there's a checkmark "Show binary contents as HEX", and this is un-checked.

There are some config fields which are set due to the old documentation, but with no effect.

How can I convince phpMyAdmin to do what I want and what I've told him to do: Show pure unconverted values from the DB ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/3885/) bug report?

I quote [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/3885/#0863) answer.

> Seems that this patch cause another problem.
>
> On milestone 4.0.1, php5.3, when a column is set to collate utf8-bin,
>   data is always displayed as hexadecimal, whatever the value of
>   display_binary_as_hex is.
>
> Looking at libraries/DisplayResults.class.php, line 5941, if php
>   version is < 5.4, then bin2hex is called every time.
>
> The check is done because of no existence of ENT_SUBSTITUTE in 5.3,
>   but i think a call without this constant is better than inconditionnel
>   call to bin2hex.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried yet, but it may help: change this line in ***config.inc.php*** from

```
$cfg['DisplayBinaryAsHex'] = true;
```

to

```
$cfg['DisplayBinaryAsHex'] = false;
```