# Binary comparison giving wrong result MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Having this DB called Employees:

```
+--+----------------+
|ID|Ability_required|
+--+----------------+
|1 |   0000000111   |
|2 |   0000001111   |
|3 |   0000000111   |
|4 |   0000001101   |
|5 |   0000001111   |
+--+----------------+
```

And this SQL query:

```
SELECT ID FROM `Employees`
WHERE `Ability_required` & b'0000001111' = b'0000001111'
```

Why does my MYSQL return row number 1 and 3? What am I doing wrong here?

Check image for an example:
[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the data type of your `Ability_required` column?

Comment: Can you paste the schema to your question?

Comment: @eggyal Now is a VARCHAR (because it seems that my version of phpmyadmin has a bug with binary fields being displayed as HEX and is very annoying http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874560/phpmyadmin-displaying-varbinary-columns-in-hex-allthough-show-in-hex-is-unchec), but tested it with BINARY and VARBINARY with same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are storing numbers as strings while [**bitwise and**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-and) operates on integers. MySQL will perform an implicit conversion, however, it assumes that the string represents a decimal number.

Convert the string manually using the MySQL [**`CONV`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv) function:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `Employees`
WHERE CONV(`Ability_required`, 2, 10) & b'0000001111' = b'0000001111';
```

```
ID Ability_required
2  0000001111
5  0000001111
```

I would suggest using an `INT` field. Or normalize the table if possible.

Comment: This is a best solution since it adapts more to what I'm doing instead of changing what I already have.

Comment: @Raulnd: Fair enough.  But be aware this wastes 8 times more storage than you need; will not scale well; and is much harder to understand/maintain than correcting the data structure so that it's done right.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that your `Especialidad_Nails` column is a string data type that contains strings of `0` and `1` *characters*.

Attempting to perform numeric operations, such as bitwise AND, on such strings will first cause MySQL to cast those strings to numbers: `'0000000111'` gets cast to decimal `111`, which is `b'1101111'`—it is this value that then undergoes the bitwise operation (and succeeds!).

If you *really* want to use a bit field, you should consider MySQL's [`SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/set.html) datatype—it is implemented as a bit field under the surface (and indeed enables you to use bitwise operations as you are attempting to do), but also exposes a more accessible interface by providing for each bit to have a human-friendly name that can very efficiently be used in operations such as [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

That said, bit operations are not sargable and bit fields do not admit many of the advantages offered by relational databases.  It's sometimes better to store each bit in its own `BOOLEAN` column.

If you have no choice but to store the bits as characters in string type columns, you can (as [@SalmanA points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28899090)) use MySQL's [`CONV()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv) function to convert to binary.

Answer (score 1):

Your data type is wrong for your ability_required columns. You have them as VARCHAR(10) and they need to be either an integer type or a bit(x) type. b'001111' only looks like a string but it is really an integer in binary representation.

```
b'001111' = 15
b'000111' = 7
b'001101' = 13
```

if you change the columns for desired_ability to INT or BIT(8) or TINYINT then your query will work as expected.

To test results try

```
SELECT ID, (`Ability_required` & b'0000001111') FROM `Employees` WHERE `Ability_required` & b'0000001111' = b'0000001111'
```

You'll see what you are getting is not bit_and that you expect.

Here is my test:

```
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ability` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `b_ability` bit(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `v_ability` VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

delete from employees;

insert into employees (ability, b_ability, v_ability) values (7,  b'000111', '000111');
insert into employees (ability, b_ability, v_ability) values (15, b'001111', '001111');
insert into employees (ability, b_ability, v_ability) values (7,  b'000111', '000111');
insert into employees (ability, b_ability, v_ability) values (13, b'001101', '001101');
insert into employees (ability, b_ability, v_ability) values (15, b'001111', '001111');

select *, (b'001111' & v_ability) from employees where v_ability & b'001111' = b'001111';
```

If you already have data that you want to keep in these columns you can convert them with a function (mysql is not my forte, may not be efficient but the function works):

```
CREATE FUNCTION `vcharbit_to_int`(bitdata varchar(16)) RETURNS int(11)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
     declare i INT DEFAULT length(bitdata);
     declare v INT default 0;
     declare b VARCHAR(1);
     declare ip INT default 1;

     while i > 0 do
        set b := SUBSTR(bitdata, i, 1);
        if b = '1' then 
            set v := v + ip;
        END IF;
        set i := i - 1;
        set ip := ip * 2;
     end while;

     RETURN v;
END
```

The query:

```
select id, v_ability from employees where vcharbit_to_int(v_ability) & b'001111' = b'001111';
```

Will give you the results you expect.

Comment: Why write your own function when `CONV()` will already perform this conversion for you?

Comment: I did say I wasn't a mysql guru. In a pinch I'll write my own function to solve a problem. It is often easier than finding what is available in the docs.